# Simple way to send mail from Docker container?

Tags: ubuntu, email, docker

I have a backup script that runs inside a Docker container and I would like it to send me an email when disk usage gets low.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
CURRENT=$(df /data | grep / | awk '{ print $5}' | sed 's/%//g')
THRESHOLD=90

echo "$CURRENT"

if [ "$CURRENT" -gt "$THRESHOLD" ] ; then
    echo "Low Disk Space Alert: ${CURRENT}% used"
  mail -s 'Disk Space Alert' olalonde@gmail.com << EOF
Backup server remaining free space is critically low. Used: $CURRENT%
EOF
fi
```

The problem is that I can't manage to get mail to work inside the container. Here's my Docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER olalonde@gmail.com
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y postfix && \
  apt-get install -y mailutils && \
  apt-get clean
ADD rootfs /
CMD /disk-alert.sh
```

I've tried a few things but the best I could do is get the mail command to complete without error (though I didn't receive anything to my email).

Is there a simple way to configure my container to be able to send mail? I don't care if the mail goes to spam as long as I receive it.

Answer (score 5):

As Jason already mentioned, I think it is indeed cleaner to separate your MTA and backup container.

I ran into this problem some time ago (although I tried to send mail from PHP instead of bash), and I discovered the [exim-sender](https://hub.docker.com/r/elsdoerfer/exim-sender/) container, which is basically a simple container that acts as an outgoing SMTP server.

Why not link your backup container to such an SMTP container? If you then [use ssmtp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36982/can-i-set-up-system-mail-to-use-an-external-smtp-server), you can send mails through the SMTP container. Or you can just use another (external) SMTP server if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider sending an email from something like Amazon SES or MailGun or any other HTTP-based mail API rather than adding an entire MTA to your container.

Or make an API call to a alerting system such as OpsGenie or PagerDuty for it.